# How do I map a nested yaml structure to Java's ConfigurationProviderBuilder?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, yaml, config

I've got some java code that creates a ConfigurationProviderBuilder.

```
private static ExampleConf conf(String confFile) {
    ConfigFilesProvider configFilesProvider =
            () -> Arrays.asList(Paths.get(confFile).toAbsolutePath());

    // use local files as config source
    ConfigurationSource source =
            new FilesConfigurationSource(configFilesProvider);

    // create provider
    return new ConfigurationProviderBuilder()
            .withConfigurationSource(source)
            .build()
            .bind("", ExampleConf.class);

}
```

ExampleConf looks like this

```
public interface ExampleConf {
    String host();
    int port();
    String certFile();
}
```

And lastly, actual config file looks like this

```
host: localhost
port: 8980
certFile: /usr2/certs/ca/ca.crt
```

This is easy enough, but now I want to create a nested structure in the yaml config file. Something like this

```
paths:
  - name: path one
    columns:
      - foo
      - bar
  - name: path two
    columns:
      - mario
      - luigi
```

How do I translate THIS ^ into java code, for use in ExampleConf?

I'm still getting up to speed with java, this would be a lot easier for me in python.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public interface ExampleConf {
    public interface MyObject {
        String name();
        List<String> columns();
    }        

    List<MyObject> paths();
}
```

Comment: Hey, this seems like a good idea. I'm now getting hit with the error

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to cast value 'path one,path two'**

Comment: Having some trouble binding it looks like. This seems like it is close though.

Comment: I have no experience with cfg4j, if I'd need to do this, I'd probably just use SnakeYaml's deserialization features. I am unsure what cfg4j's abstraction adds to that.